# Knockout js - unknown syntax error

Tags: magento2.3, knockoutjs

This is a part from  `Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.phtml` file:

```
<dl class="product options list">
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
    <dt class="label aaa" data-bind="i18n: option.label"></dt>
    <dd class="values">
        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
            <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
            <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </dd>
    <!-- /ko -->
</dl>
```

Adding the following line inside that foreach loop, breaks content.

```
<span data-bind="html: custom_variable_data"></span>
```

But the same line (span) works ok anywhere else in the code file.
Am I missing some kind of syntax rule here?

Comment: Where you set your custom property `custom_variable_data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ko render specified template it using current context, which is `item` in your case. If current item has no property `custom_variable_data` you will se an error like that one:

[image: error exmaple]

If you want to call a parent property (minicart property) you can access it using the `$parent` context like this:

```
<span data-bind="html: $parent.custom_variable_data"></span>
```

but parent must have that property.

**PS:** syntax is right

Comment: $parent did the trick